# How to know the tag type of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that receives by parameter an object.
Can I know if this object is a div, or a tr, or anything else?

My code:

```
function test(obj1, obj2){
    alert($.type(obj1) + " --- " + $.type(obj2));
}
function...{
    ...
    test($(this), $(this).parent());
    ...
}
```

With this I can only see "object --- object" in alert. Is it possible to know what object it is?

Comment: My problem was: I needed to take a <table> that is parent of a <tr>, but it didn't work... The mistake was that the parent of <tr> was <tbody> instead of <table>. In all cases, thanks for the answers, and sorry by the duplicate question (wasn't intentional).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element.tagName
```

Really simple, use the `tagName` property of the element you want the type of. jQuery not necessary.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName

In the context of your code:

```
function test(obj1, obj2){
    alert(obj1.get(0).tagName + " --- " + obj2.get(0).tagName);
}

test($(this), $(this).parent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with tagName like

```
$(this).prop("tagName")
```